# A question on point-wise/uniform convergence of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Let $\{f_n(\cdot)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real-valued functions defined on $[0, k]$ for some $0 < k < 1$. Suppose that for every fixed $x \in [0,k]$, we have the point-wise convergence
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0.
\end{equation}
The question is: if I let $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of arbitrary points in $[0,k]$. Then does it hold that
\begin{equation}
\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} | f_n(x_n) | < \infty?
\end{equation}

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no.

Here is a counter example:
$f_n(x):[0,\frac{2}{3}] \to \mathbb R$ with $f_1(x)=0$ and for $n \geq 2$
$$f_n(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lc}
n^2x &\mbox{ if } 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n} \\
2n-n^2x  &\mbox{ if } \frac{1}{n} < x < \frac{2}{n} \\
0 &\mbox{ if } x >\frac{2}{n}\\
\end{array}
\right.$$

Note that $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ gives you what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So other than directly assuming uniform convergence, is Dini's theorem the "simplest" way to guarantee $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} | f_n(x_n) | < \infty$?

Comment: @Richie Well it depends on what you really want/are willing to assume. Basically what you ask is the following question : if $f_n$ converge pointwise on a compact interval, what else do you need to add to obtain equi boundedness....Well, equiboundedness is the simplest extra condition you can add :) But you are probably right, Dini theorem is one of the simplest most meaningfull result in this situation.... Alternately, because of the compactness, if $f_n$ are equi uniformly continuous, I think the claim follows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. So if the condition is that on *every* closed subinterval of $(0,k)$, it holds that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $0$, then does this mean that $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly equibounded on some interval $[0, a]$ with $0 < a \leqslant k$?

Comment: @Richie If $f_n$ converges uniformly on some interval $(0,k]$ then, there exists some $N$ such that, for all $n >N$ you have $$\|f_n-0\|_\infty <1$$ Then, $\{f_n \}$ is uniformly equibounded by $\max \{ 1, \|f _1\|_\infty,..., \|f _N\|_\infty\}$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments, but I think what you said works for the uniformly equiboundedness of $\{f_n\}$ on some closed interval $[a, k]$ (if this is the interval where uniform convergence is assumed). But does this also imply uniform equiboundedness on $[0, a)$? This is why I want to ask what if we have uniform convergence on *every* such $[a,k]$ but with $0<a<k$. Does this imply uniform equiboundedness on $[0, k]$?

Comment: @Richie I think that $\frac{1}{(1-x)^n}$ is uniformly equibounded and uniformly continuous on each $[0,a)$ for $a<1$ but not on $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

No. Suppose that:

- $f_n$ is an affine function on $\left[0,\frac k{4n}\right]$ with $f_n(0)=0$ and $f_n\left(\frac k{4n}\right)=n$;
- $f_n$ is an affine function on $\left[\frac k{4n},\frac k{2n}\right]$ with $f_n\left(\frac k{4n}\right)=n$ and $f_n\left(\frac k{2n}\right)=0$;
- $f_n$ is the null function on $\left[\frac k{2n},k\right]$.

Then $f_n\left(\frac k{4n}\right)=n$ for each $n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So other than directly assuming uniform convergence, is Dini's theorem the "simplest" way to guarantee $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} | f_n(x_n) | < \infty$?

Comment: Dini's theorem is a way of assuring that the convergence is uniform. But I don't know if you can say that it is the simplest one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. So if the condition is that on *every* closed subinterval of $(0,k)$, it holds that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $0$, then does this mean that $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly equibounded on some interval $[0, a]$ with $0 < a \leqslant k$?

Answer (score 1):

No, let $f_{n}:[0,k]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be given by
$$f_{n}(x)=\begin{cases}n&\text{ if }x=\frac{1}{n}\\0&\text{ else}\end{cases}.$$
Clearl pointwise $f_{n}$ converges to $0$, but $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(\frac{1}{n})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n=\infty.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. So other than directly assuming uniform convergence, is Dini's theorem the "simplest" way to guarantee $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} | f_n(x_n) | < \infty$?

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered. To answer a question the OP asks in comments on the answers: It's easy to  see that $\sup_nf_n(x_n)<\infty$ for *every* sequence $x_n$ if and only if the $f_n$ are uniformly bounded ($f_n(x)\le C$ for every $n$ and every $x$.)

And, since it seems possible that this is what you really want to know: It's also easy to see that $f_n(x_n)\to0$ for every sequence $(x_n)$ if and only if $f_n\to0$ uniformly.